# Splitting file with If-Then-Else into 3 files

Tags: shell, perl, ksh

Why code to split large file written in Perl running much faster the code written in Korn Shell. Over a million input records. The first 9 characters of each record are used to determine which file the record is written to, and it runs in about 4-5 minutes in Perl.
I have attempted to convert this code to ksh and it seems to run forever (hours).

I really have no clue what I have done wrong that is causing this problem. In some of the records there is a blank and/or alpha characters embedded in the string so the comparison must be a string type comparison. Any ideas about making my ksh script get the perl performance or why it is not ?

I have tried several different options since ksh/bash tends to have a lot of ways to do the same or similar things in handling variables and comparisons. I also do not have a good handle on exactly how this very old Perl code is operating.

My Perl Code:

```perl
open(FILEIN,"base.dat") || die "Could not open FILEIN\n.";

open(FILEOUT1,">base1.dat") || die "Could not open FILEOUT1\n.";
open(FILEOUT2,">base2.dat") || die "Could not open FILEOUT2\n.";
open(FILEOUT3,">base3.dat") || die "Could not open FILEOUT3\n.";

$v_break =  "518000000";
$v_break2 = "525000000";

#Run until end of file
while (<FILEIN>)   {
  $v_pcn = substr($_, 0, 9);

  if ($v_break gt $v_pcn) {
     print FILEOUT1 $_;
  }
  elsif (($v_pcn ge $v_break) && ($v_pcn lt $v_break2)) {
     print FILEOUT2 $_;
  }
  else
  {
    print FILEOUT3 $_;
  }
}  #(<FILEIN>)

close(FILEIN);
close(FILEOUT1);
close(FILEOUT2);
close(FILEOUT3);
```

My Shell script (ksh):

```ksh
while read inrec                           # Read base file until EOF
 do                                        # Start work loop
    v_pcn=${inrec:0:9}                     # Get 1st 9 Characters in v_pcn
#   v_pcn=${v_pcn/' '/0}                   # Replace blanks with '0'
    if [[ $v_pcn < '518000000' ]]; then    # pcn < "518000000"
         echo $inrec >> base1.dat          # write rec to "base1.dat"
    elif [[ $v_pcn > '525000000' || $v_pcn == '525000000' ]]; then  # pcn >= "525000000"
         echo $inrec >> base3.dat          # write rec to "base3.dat"
    else                                   # else >= "518000000" & < "525000000"
         echo $inrec >> base2.dat          # write rec to "base2.dat"
    fi
 done < base.dat
```

I expect the shell script to produce 3 output files matching those produced by the perl code and about the same amount of time;

input:

```
-rw-r--r--. 1 mfadjobt mfadset 2095795750 Feb 13 10:07 base.dat
```

Output:

```
-rw-r--r--. 1 mfadjobt mfadset  461650125 Feb 13 10:07 base1.dat
-rw-r--r--. 1 mfadjobt mfadset  519783625 Feb 13 10:07 base2.dat
-rw-r--r--. 1 mfadjobt mfadset 1114362000 Feb 13 10:07 base3.dat
```

Answer (score 3):

Each time you have `>> filename`, you're opening the file again, moving the pointer to the end of the file, and then closing the file again at the end of the statement. Better to keep the files open.

```
while read inrec                           # Read base file until EOF
 do                                        # Start work loop
    v_pcn=${inrec:0:9}                     # Get 1st 9 Characters in v_pcn
#   v_pcn=${v_pcn/' '/0}                   # Replace blanks with '0'
    if [[ $v_pcn < '518000000' ]]; then    # pcn < "518000000"
         echo $inrec >&3
    elif [[ $v_pcn > '525000000' || $v_pcn == '525000000' ]]; then  # pcn >= "525000000"
         echo $inrec >&4
    else                                   # else >= "518000000" & < "525000000"
         echo $inrec >&5
    fi
 done < base.dat 3>> base1.dat 4>> base2.dat 5>> base3.dat
```

This will open the files once, maintain their pointers into the files, and should help speed things up immensely.

Normally when shell is slow, it's due to the commands you're running, but nothing here spawns subshells, so then I look at the next most likely culprit - file handling. And that's what I see here.

Comment: If I may, since it's in ksh, instead of using echo which is an external utility, should use "print -u {file handler number} " since print is internal.

Comment: Will try this immediately. Thanks.

Comment: Thank You Tanktalus ! That change has made a dramatic change in the speed. I am going to switch to the "print" command suggested by Andre next which I believe will make additional improvements. I am also wondering in the elif comparison I wanted to figure out how to execute the equivalent of a -ge in a string comparison rather than the compound comparisin I am using in this code which might also make a small improvement but not much. Though I wonder internally if  the difference is not worth it if internally there is only one time that the second condition would ever come into play.

Comment: @AndreGelinas In my ksh, `type echo` says `echo is a shell builtin`

Answer (score 2):

Perl code is compiled into a "binary" representation. Then that binary representation is executed by a highly optimized interpreter.

Shell scripts on the other hand

- parse each line every time it gets executed,
- file redirections are repeated every time they get executed,
- usually execute *external* commands, except if the command happens to be a shell builtin.

I'm not sure what builtins the Korn shell has, but bash has quite a few of them.

Executing external commands is *expensive* as it involves at least a `fork()` and a `execve()` system calls.

In general a shell script will only be faster than a Perl script when it is extremely short, i.e. when the startup cost of the Perl compiler is higher than the actual code execution time.

The short answer: don't be surprised when you translate a shell script into an equivalent Perl script that it will run much faster.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid confusion with file descriptors , you can use for loop.

```
for inrec in `cat base.dat`                           # Read base file until EOF
 do                                        # Start work loop
    v_pcn=${inrec:0:9}                     # Get 1st 9 Characters in v_pcn
#   v_pcn=${v_pcn/' '/0}                   # Replace blanks with '0'
    if [[ $v_pcn < '518000000' ]]; then    # pcn < "518000000"
         echo $inrec >> base1.dat          # write rec to "base1.dat"
    elif [[ $v_pcn > '525000000' || $v_pcn == '525000000' ]]; then  # pcn >= "525000000"
         echo $inrec >> base3.dat          # write rec to "base3.dat"
    else                                   # else >= "518000000" & < "525000000"
         echo $inrec >> base2.dat          # write rec to "base2.dat"
    fi
 done
```

Answer (score 0):

Only tested with `bash`, but the next solution should work with some `ksh` versions too.
First reconsider the boundaries. The beautiful round figures allow us to look at the first 3 characters. This should benefit you in all solutions.
With `tee` you can write to stdout and a file, but also to different processes.

```
tee < base.dat \
    >(grep -E "^([0-4]|50|51[0-7])"    > base1.dat) \
    >(grep -E "^5(1[89]|2[0-4])"       > base2.dat) |
      grep -E "^(52[5-9]|5[3-9]|6-9])" > base3.dat
```